# Firefox bookmark with wildcard and keyword

Tags: firefox, shortcuts, url, wildcards

In Firefox, how do I set up URL shortcuts that include a wildcard, %s?  I have definitely set this up before on another computer.

For example, if I wanted to view a Jira ticket, I would enter `jira XXX-1234` into the address bar and it would take me to `http://jira.meanwhileinhell.com:1234/browse/XXX-1234`.  I remember the entry added to Firefox would be `http://jira.meanwhileinhell.com:1234/browse/%s`, but I can't remember where I add that.

**EDIT**

I might add, I have done this without any additional addons.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just found out the answer.  You add a new bookmark with the %s and give it a keyword.  Example

```
Name: Bugs
Location: http://jira.sutureself.com:1234/browse/%s
Keyword: bug
```

Typing `bug XXX-1234` now brings you to `http://jira.sutureself.com:1234/browse/XXX-1234`