# How can I create "keyword shortcuts" for Firefox searches?

Tags: firefox, keyboard-shortcuts, search, bookmarks

Back in the day, it was possible to define [Keyword Shortcuts](http://dmcritchie.mvps.org/firefox/kws.htm), also known as [Custom keywords](http://www-archive.mozilla.org/docs/end-user/keywords.html) in Mozilla.

These were similar to [Smart keywords](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/how-search-from-address-bar), except that they were defined from within the bookmark dialog, and they allowed a `%s` search for any item on the right side of the `=` in an HTTP [GET](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Request_methods), e.g. setting up a keyword shortcut `g` on `www.google.com?q=%s` would allow you to type

```
g firefox "keyword shortcuts"
```

In the address bar, and Firefox would expand this to

```
www.google.com?q=firefox "keyword shortcuts"
```

The current "smart keywords" feature only allows you to define shortcuts for searches where there is an existing search bar on a page.

Does the older, more powerful feature still exist in Firefox, and if so, how do I access it?

Comment: Related: *[Firefox bookmark with wildcard and keyword](https://superuser.com/questions/661116/)*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it available. You add it using the below steps.

- Do a search on the site you want to add a quicksearch to.
- Bookmark the page you are brought to (the results page).
- Open the Properties dialog for your new bookmark.
- In your bookmark’s URL (the Location field), find and replace what you searched for with `%s` (if it does not appear, you cannot use a quicksearch here)
- Add a keyword

It will also work like a charm when you search with the keyword in the latest version of Firefox.

Comment: Yep. That worked. In firefox 26.0, This requires right-clicking on the bookmark to get to the properties; the properties are no longer available by simply editing the bookmark.

Comment: Still works four years later in Firefox Quantum 61.0.2.